# Current browser/system support for <a href="skype:some_id"> (with Microsoft live-ids)?

Tags: html, protocols, href, skype

I vaguely remember that once one could place a link like in the following example on a website and a click on it (if the user had Skype installed) would fire up a Skype window and try to call/chat to the linked account:

```
<a href="skype:some_id">Call me on Skype</a>
```

There were even some browser addons for handling the "Skype-protocol" correctly. Today, Skype recommends to [include a piece code which pulls in some javascript file from Microsoft's CDN](https://www.skype.com/en/developer/create-contactme-buttons/) instead.

**What's the current (2017) situation in terms of browser support across operating systems for skype-links like in my example assuming that I do not want to pull stuff from Microsoft's CDN?** *Firefox 52 64bit on openSUSE Linux with default settings and no addons asks whether it should open Skype, so there is still some support for this method around. Chrome 58 on openSUSE does more or less the same.*

Given the fact that this still works at least partially, how would one link to a Microsoft live id, which contains a colon? The following does **not** work unfortunately:

```
<a href="skype:live%3Asome_id">Call me on Skype</a>
```

Both Firefox and Chrome fire up Skype, which then tries to call "live%3asome_id". Not escaping the colon kind of does not seem to work either ...

Comment: Microsoft is consistently destroying Skype as a communication platform.